# multi-language builds with gnatbench

Tags: ada, gnat

I'm trying to build a multi-language project in gnatbench (C/C++) and it just ignores building my c++ code. my project file looks like:

```
 project Ralt_Pss is

  for Main use ("locationalpsses_part_main.adb");
  for Languages use ("Ada", "C", "C++");
  for Source_Dirs use ("../../../AdaExamples/CPP", "src","../../../AdaExamples/ARINC653", "../../../ada_common/face");
  for Object_Dir use "obj";

 package Compiler is
    for Default_Switches ("ada") use ("-g", "-gnato", "-gnatwa", "-gnatQ", "-gnat05");
 end Compiler;

 package Builder is
    for Default_Switches ("ada") use ("-g");
  end Builder;

 package Ide is
 end Ide;

 package Naming is
    for Spec_Suffix ("c++") use ".h";
    for Body_Suffix ("c++") use ".cc";
 end Naming;

 end Ralt_Pss;
```

GPS seems to build it properly, but gnatbench doesn't.Also, I've noticed that gnatbench builds using gnatmake, and GPS builds using gprbuild. Any idea how to fix this besides just not using gnatbench?

Comment: You need gprbuild for multi-language projects. I'm afraid I don't know how to tell eclipse to do that (I suppose you could grep for `gnatmake` in the gnatbench `.xml` files). Googling "tell gnatbench to use gprbuild" shows that AdaCore fixed this 7 Aug 2012, you'll probably need to wait a few months for GNAT GPL 2013 for the fix to be released publicly though.

Comment: If that was the right answer, shall I make it an answer rather than a comment so you can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need gprbuild for multi-language projects.

I'm afraid I don't know for sure how to tell Eclipse to do that; you could try changing `gnatmake` in the gnatbench `.xml` files to `gprbuild`.

Googling "tell gnatbench to use gprbuild" shows that AdaCore fixed this 7 Aug 2012, you'll probably need to wait a few months for GNAT GPL 2013 for the fix to be released publicly though.